# How do i get key in php json data

Tags: php, json

I managed to get all the data in loops one by one. But I only want to get the 2 questions inside the 'maths' object and when I try other methods I get different errors.
Ex: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

JSON:

```
{
"quiz": {
    "sport": {
        "q1": {
            "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",
            "options": [
                "New York Bulls",
                "Los Angeles Kings",
                "Golden State Warriros",
                "Huston Rocket"
            ],
            "answer": "Huston Rocket"
        }
    },
    "maths": {
        "q1": {
            "question": "5 + 7 = ?",
            "options": [
                "10",
                "11",
                "12",
                "13"
            ],
            "answer": "12"
        },
        "q2": {
            "question": "12 - 8 = ?",
            "options": [
                "1",
                "2",
                "3",
                "4"
            ],
            "answer": "4"
        }
    }
}
```

}

PHP Codes:

```
$jsonFile = json_decode(file_get_contents('example_2.json', true));
function getMathQuestions($jsonFile) {
    foreach($jsonFile as $val) {
        if(is_object($val)) {
            getMathQuestions($val);
        } else {
            if(is_array($val)) {
                getMathQuestions($val);
            } else {
                echo $val . "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
echo getMathQuestions($jsonFile);
```

Comment: This code does *not* produce that error: https://3v4l.org/OMjaA

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249728/discussion-between-deceze-and-lk77).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing json_decode parameter `associative`, if not specified you will get stdClass object instead of php array of data.

So change line:

`$jsonFile = json_decode(file_get_contents('example_2.json', true));`

to:

`$jsonFile = json_decode(file_get_contents('example_2.json', true), true);`

Comment: Probably a typo on OP's part, the `true` parameter was probably meant for `json_decode` instead of `file_get_contents`.

Comment: He wouldnt get error cannont use object of type stdClass as array if that was case

Comment: Thanks for comment. As you said, I was giving the value 'true' to the wrong function. Solved now!